# Can you sell your properties for cheap to another player in Monopoly?

Tags: monopoly

Is it possible for example to sell a property you own to another player for 1$? I was playing with some friends and one of them had to pay me 1200$ and since he didnt have enough he sold all his houses reached 1200 gave me the money and then sold all his stuff for 1$ to another player.

Comment: Dupe but slight variation, in this question the person has already settled their debts and is now just selling off property before choosing to quit. (ie the player isn't about to lose, but about to choose to leave)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can sell your properties cheap.

No, you can't do this when you are resolving payment for the space you landed on.

From [Can you force property onto players in Monopoly](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/22504/can-you-force-property-onto-players-in-monopoly/22507#22507)

> The only time a sale cannot take place is if a player will be cheated.
>   For example, Player A lands on Boardwalk with hotels and owes $2,000
>   to Player B. Player A cannot raise enough cash or make a trade with
>   Player B, so he is effectively bankrupt and should turn over all
>   assets. Player A would not be able to make a deal with Player C to
>   sell some properties for less than their value (say the red properties
>   for $1) since that would cheat Player B. He could sell them for more
>   than their purchase value, however.